# Eccentricity Vector as a function of position only, as seen on Wikipedia?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I am looking into some Lambert's solver-type research and came across this wonderful formula on Wikipedia at the bottom of the Lambert's Solver page, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem#Parametrization_of_the_transfer_trajectories).  It has a parameterization gamma, a normal vector N, and then eccentricity and semilatus rectum equations.  But they're all a function of position alone, assuming you know two positions:

[image]

Besides the change in length notation halfway through the eccentricity vector it seems like a killer set of equations since semilatus rectum and eccentricity are both functions of two radii only.  It seems almost too good to be true, so I tried looking at the sources for the article and wasn't able to find this derivation or even these equations.  I'm left scratching my head wondering how this came about.

Does anyone have any kind of derivation for it?  Or know what's going on?  Let me know if you have any information as I'm super interested in this parameterization that doesn't even require the gravitational parameter.  Thanks!

Edit:
After a good night's rest I'm realizing I wasn't clear with what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to figure out how they managed to get an eccentricity vector with no velocity and no gravitational parameter.  I am also looking for what reference frame this was derived in/if it can be used in an ecliptic and not a perifocal frame.  I imagine it can be but that's kind of why I was looking for a source so I can follow and make sure.  I looked through space stack exchange too and couldn't find anything.  Please let me know if anyone knows anything!

Comment: it is possible that there's some insight available already here in Space SE. This returns 41 hits, perhaps some are helpful. https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22eccentricity+vector%22

Comment: That does seem super weird.  Given two position vectors, and the placement of the central body, I think that [isn't enough information](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55294/22816) to staple down the magnitude or direction of the eccentricity vector.

Comment: Ah, I see. It only gives you the eccentricity vector without gravitational parameter or velocity in two special cases (extremal and parabolic). $\gamma$ would  require more parameters outside of those special cases.

Comment: And thinking about it a little further, there isn't a _unique_ parabola that's defined by a focus and two position vectors, so  the $\gamma_p$ that produces a parabola seems to be just picking one that satisfies the requirements and is easy to calculate. Still not sure what's the uses is of finding the extremal case of $\gamma$

Comment: Thanks @ notovny.  That makes sense and I figured my way out of needing the equation for the problem I've been trying to solve.  Passing curiosity, though, do you know what the extremal case means?  is it the minimum energy ellipse?  or something else?  I tried googling it and wasn't able to find anything.  If you have any insight let me know, otherwise this will just be a passing oddity in my search.  Thanks!